# python regex matching space or nothing

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex expression that will match space or nothing. I use this for finding blocks with classes inside a string containing HTML code.

Now my pattern looks:

```
pattern = r'class="([A-Za-z0-9_\./\\-]*)"'
```

But it doesn't catch the 'class = "some class names"'
Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: add `\s*`. I would suggest to use a dedicated parser such as beautifulsoup :)

Comment: It is possible to use `class=(["'])(.*?)\1"` to match what you want with a regex, but ... hush... :)

Answer (score 2):

Better to use HTML Parser, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
print soup.find_all(tag_name, class_name)
```

Demo:

```
>>> html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>

<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and  their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
>>> soup.find_all('p', 'title')
[<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>]
>>> soup.find_all('a')
[<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>, <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]
```